# Ubuntu 18.04 Live Damaged My LCD Screen? Flicker + Burn In?

Tags: 18.04, screen, flicker

So i've been running Ubuntu 18.04 from a Live USB recently. I noticed that whenever I was in Ubuntu the screen sometimes randomly flickered at the corners a bit, but then eventually stopped. The problem never happened in Windows.

Today while working in Ubuntu the flicker became very strong. I shut down the system and booted back into Windows but noticed that now the flicker remained, and what's more the Ubuntu desktop was burned into my LCD screen.

I have a Geforce 1080TI Graphics card and a Philips 278C4 monitor, with HDMI connection.

So the question is what could have done this? I have an identical monitor which I can use for now, but am afraid to boot back into Ubuntu to get my files out in case the issue happens again. Secondly, is my monitor destroyed now? I've powered it off and will try it again in a day or so.

My first guess is that Ubuntu set my LCD to an unsupported refresh rate which caused issues?

Comment: Try moving your monitor cable around.  I purchased a brand new monitor that was doing close to the same thing, and I discovered that some sort of power or something causing interference next to the cable was causing `ghosting` that looked like screen burnin.

Comment: Definitely not the cabling, I already tried moving it around, and using the same cables on my second monitor causes no issues.

I'm confident that it was caused by Ubuntu as i've never seen the screen flicker outside of Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you actually tried checking the Display settings in Ubuntu and make sure that the Refresh Rate is set for your monitor?  One way that I can think of to test your monitor because we would not be able to tell you if it is destroyed or not is to try it on another computer and cable just to make sure.

Comment: Yeah it's doing the same thing on another PC too. I'm a bit afraid to boot Ubuntu UI now. If something is wrong it might damage my other screen...